# How to continuously show latitude and longitude in a Toast message?

Tags: android, gps

I want to display latitude and longitude continuously in toast...
If user moves then lat long should be change... the following code only pops up lat long when it is installed it is not changing...
I want lat long without internet means only from GPS...

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.techblogon.serviceexample;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

MyService.java

```
package com.techblogon.serviceexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service{
    GPSTracker gps;
    static int i=0;
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyService.this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt("key", 0);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    gps = new GPSTracker(MyService.this);
    i=0;

    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
         public void run() 
         {
             if(getI()==0)
             {
              latlong();
              startService(new Intent(MyService.this,MyService.class));
             }
         }
     }, 5000);


    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");  
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    i=1;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyService.this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt("key", 1);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

public int getI()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt("key",0);
}

public void latlong()
{
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
package com.techblogon.serviceexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    //start the service
    public void onClickStartServie(View V)
    {
        //start the service from here //MyService is your service class name
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
    //Stop the started service
    public void onClickStopService(View V)
    {
        //Stop the running service from here//MyService is your service class name
        //Service will only stop if it is already running.
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text=" " />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_service"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Start Service"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_header"
        android:onClick="onClickStartServie" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_service"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Stop Service"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_service"
        android:onClick="onClickStopService" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.techblogon.serviceexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.techblogon.serviceexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />

    </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Please give me the code where i need to change....????

Answer (score 1):

Use your `LocationManager` to **set the refresh rate** of your location:

```
LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

Then, inside your `onLocationChanged(Location l)` method, post the `Toast` message:

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long: " + location.getLongitude() + ", Lat: " + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This will fire a `Toast` message everytime **the location of the user changes**.

Comment: Why? Error message? You need to be a bit more specific if you want help.